# making materials unique to an object

Tags: materials

I have two different objects that have the same material applied to them. I want the material to be unique to each so that I can edit it for one object without changing the other. Why is this so difficult in Blender?

Comment: It is not difficult in Blender. You question must be lacking some crucial information, otherwise the answer from @Lutzi should work. Could you at the very least show a screenshot of Blender where we can see the _3D Viewport_ with the objects, the _Outliner_ and the _Material Properties_ tab showing the material slot?

Comment: Hello, as the others say we lack informations here, maybe share your file, only the 2 objects you are talking about, maybe the 2 objects share the same Image Texture? In that case you need to create a new image...

Answer (score 1):

To duplicate current material and making it unique, click the page icon (orange) :

[image: Where to click to make material unique]

It will create a new material based on the current one. A copy, but not linked to the original.

You can monitor how many objects use the selected material with the number (blue).

Comment: Thanks for that, but it doesn't work. I currently have a wall object and a head object, both with the same material. Pressing the page icon as you indicated does not make the material unique to each. I can alter the color on one, but it's affecting both.

Comment: Then I don't understand and the only thing that comes to mind is that one of your object is a linked copy of the other.

Comment: How would I unlinked them?

Comment: How can a wall and a head be linked objects? But I agree, there must be some information @Zdepthcharge has left out, otherwise this should work. You can also click on the number, but clicking the copy icon should always work (even when you are in _Edit Mode_ where clicking the number does not work). Are those not two separate objects, but just one object with two meshes? Is there a number to the left of the copy icon?